# How to add 1 to a value after x amount of increments?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add 1 to a variable, wait 5 iterations of a loop, and then add 1 again.

For example:

(where x = 10 and the coefficient is the number of iterations)

`(5x(10)) + (5x + 1(10)) + (5x + 1 + 1(10)),`

and so on

The code below can count these iterations `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and then back to 0)` but I'm unsure where to go when it comes to adding a 1 after the repeat.

```
for(i = 0; i < input; i++){
  output = i%5
}
```

Comment: Can you not add 1 before and then do the loop?

Comment: can you provide with more details what do you need? (5x(10)) + (5x + 1(10)) + (5x + 1 + 1(10)), and so on - what are we doing in this string?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. It should be (5x(10 + 1)). 5 = the amount of iterations, x is the variable, so 5*x and 10 is just a random number I pulled. Each time, the amount that 10 is increased by goes up by 1 -- hence 10 + 1 +1 and whatnot.

Comment: Is this >>> 5*(10+0) + 5*(10+1) + 5*(10+2) + ... 5*(10+N) is what you need?

Comment: yep, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works like: 5*(10+0) + 5*(10+1) + 5*(10+2) + ... 5*(10+N)

```js
"use strict";

let input = 100;
let iterationsAmount = 5;
let randomNumber = 10;
let value = 0;
let result = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    if (!(i % iterationsAmount)) {
        result += iterationsAmount * (randomNumber + value);
        value++;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// set a default number.
var num = 20;


function loopi(n){

    // variable to assign number to.
    var setNum = 0;

    // loop through the default number of times.
    for( var ii = 0; n > ii; ii++){

        // if the iteration number is divisible by 5 the add one to the set number.
        if(ii % 5 === 0){
            setNum++;
        }
    }
return setNum;
}


console.log(loopi(num));
```